# WPF change dynamicresource in codebehind

Tags: wpf, radio-button, controltemplate

The standard RadioButton does not support setting the color of the ellipse. So, I took a radiobutton template from this location as a basis for a custom RadioButton:
[RadioButton Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751600)

```
<Ellipse.Fill>
<LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
    <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
        <GradientStopCollection>
            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" />
            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlMediumColor}" Offset="1.0" />
        </GradientStopCollection>
    </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

ControlLightColor and ControlMediumColor are defined as:

```
<Color x:Key="ControlLightColor">#ffff9a</Color>
<Color x:Key="ControlMediumColor">#ffff9a</Color>
```

Which gives us a yellow-ish ellipse.

How can I alter this color in the codebehind?

Regards,

Michel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
<Ellipse x:Name="Border" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.RadioButtonColor}">

        Public ReadOnly Property RadioButtonColor() As SolidColorBrush
        Get
            Dim solidColorBrush As SolidColorBrush

            If MyBusinessLogic Then
                solidColorBrush = _radioButtonNotRequiredBrush
            Else
                solidColorBrush = _radioButtonRequiredBrush
            End If

            Return solidColorBrush
        End Get
    End Property
```

Thumbs up for JRB for thinking along.

Answer (score 0):

Create a style by following this:
[Creating a Style in code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729368/creating-a-style-in-code-behind)

then assign it to your element.Style

You can also access resources by

```
Resources["mykey"]
```

Comment: I updated the Application.Current.Resources("ControlLightColor") with a different color, nothing happens. I also did a RaisePropertyChanged on my binding element, also doesn't work.

Comment: maybe you have to call InitializeComponent(); It's probably better to crate two styles and just switch style. Or bind the gradientstop color to a property (MVVM)

Comment: Right hmm, then the only thin I can think about is creating new styles.. What is it that you are trying to accomplish btw? Maybe its easier to do in xaml

Comment: I have a stackpanel with an itemscontrol that displays multiple radiobuttons. The radiobuttons have a color to indicate that one of them must be chosen. when a radiobutton is clicked, all radiobuttons must change to a different color indicating that the mandatory question has been answered. Without doing some templatework, it's not possible to give a radiobutton a color. I was thinking about controltemplate triggers, but all of the rb's have to get the new color, not just the one clicked.

Comment: Hmm this looks promising: binding to ellipse <ellipse fill="{binding etc.. I'll give it a go and report back.