# Set style of TextBlock programmatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have this:

```
var MyText = new TextBlock();
MyText.Text = "blah";
MyText.Style = /* ??? */;
```

In XAML, I can set a style like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="blah" Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}"/>
```

But how do I do that in C#?

**EDIT:**

```
Error   1   'Windows.UI.Xaml.Application' does not contain a definition for 'FindResource' and no extension method 'FindResource' accepting a first argument of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Application' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error   1   'Geodropper.HubPage' does not contain a definition for 'FindResource' and no extension method 'FindResource' accepting a first argument of type 'Geodropper.HubPage' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

When I tried `(Style)this.FindResource("ListViewItemTextBlockStyle");` and `(Style)App.Current.FindResource("ListViewItemTextBlockStyle")` I got these errors.

Comment: something like `MyText.Style = (Style)this.FindResource("ListViewItemTextBlockStyle");` where this is your window or the element containing the resource or `(Style)App.Current.FindResource("ListViewItemTextBlockStyle")`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729368/creating-a-style-in-code-behind and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686917/setting-the-style-property-of-a-wpf-label-in-code

Comment: @decoherence neither of those worked for me.

Comment: @ZudoMC sorry thought you were using WPF, otherwise `(Style)App.Current.Resources["ListViewItemTextBlockStyle"]` or `(Style)this.Resources["ListViewItemTextBlockStyle"]`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Thank you decoherence! What I needed was the following:

```
var MyText = new TextBlock();
MyText.Text = drop;
MyText.Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["ListViewItemTextBlockStyle"];
```